# Rock Paper Scissors Program

Tags: java

I have to make a very simple rock, paper, scissors game for my class. I am usually decent with these assignments but I have been working on this particular one for about 8 hours now and I know it shouldnt be taking this long and I have to be missing something.

We are in the very early stages of the class and I want to make sure I am doing the assignment correctly. We have gone over ints, doubles, boolean expressions, chars and strings. We just got to if and else if statements so I want to avoid implementing techniques that we have not covered in class yet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RPSFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user;
        char R, P, S;
        R = '1';
        P = '2';
        S = '3';
        int compInt = (int) (3*Math.random())+1;
        System.out.print("Rock, Paper, Scissors-Enter a choice R/P/S: ");
        user = keyboard.nextLine();
        user = user.toUpperCase();
        char chUser = user.charAt(0);   

        if (chUser == compInt)
        {
            System.out.println("We chose the same item-try again");
        }
        else if (chUser == R)
        {
            if (compInt == P)
                System.out.println("1");
            else if (compInt == S)
                System.out.println("2");
        }
        else if (chUser == P)
        {
            if (compInt == R)
                System.out.println("3");
            else if (compInt == S)
                System.out.println("4");
        }
        else if (chUser == S)
        {
            if (compInt == R)
                System.out.println("5");
            else if (compInt == P)
                System.out.println("6");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("User error.");
    }
}
```

### Edit

I am not sure what I need to do to get the program working. Every time I enter r, p, or s, the program just returns "User Error".

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you're looking for review of your code, you might consider [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that you are prompting the user to enter 'R', 'P' or 'S', but comparing their selection against '1', '2' and '3'.

Comment: I am not sure what I need to do to get the program working. Every time i enter r, p, or s, the program just returns "User Error"

Comment: Easiest way to change this would be to advice the user to enter an integer instead of char (`System.out.print("Rock, Paper, Scissors-Enter a choice 1 (=R) / 2 (=P) / 3 (=S): ");`).

Comment: And change the computer's selection to into a `char`: `char compInt = Character.forDigit((int)(3*Math.random())+1, 10);`

Comment: Probably use :`System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors-Enter a choice R/P/S: ");`, to print a new line

Answer (score 0):

Each time the user enters `'R'`, `'P'` or `'S'`, you are comparing that character against a variable **named** `R`, `P` or `S`, which contain the character values of `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'` respectively.

Hence, they are never equal and you always get the user error message.

You need to either change the prompt to make it clear that the user needs to enter a number, or you need to change your comparison logic.

Additionally, even if that is fixed, you are storing the computer's random move as an `int`, but trying to compare it against `char` values to get a result.

I would suggest creating a `chComp` variable storing the character representation of the computer's move so that everything is consistent:

```
    char chComp = 0;
    if (compInt == 1) {
        chComp = 'R';
    } else if (compInt == 2) {
        ...
    } //etc
```

Then you can ditch the `R`, `P` and `S` variables entirely and do direct character comparison:

```
    if (chUser == chComp) {
        System.out.println("We chose the same item-try again");
    } else if (chUser == 'R') {
        if (chComp == 'P')
            System.out.println("1");
        else if (chComp == 'S')
            System.out.println("2");
    ...
```

Comment: I got rid of the R, P, and S variables and changed my code around to better match the info you provided. The only issue im having right now is an error stating "The local variable chComp may not have been initialized". I am not really sure how to go about initializing it. Thank you for the quick and helpful replies though, they are much appreciated

Comment: The computer's choice could also be selected in a one-liner: `char chComp = Arrays.asList('R', 'P', 'S').get(new Random().nextInt(3));` (making `compInt` redundant).

Comment: @azurefrog That did the trick, you saved me a ton of hassle. Instead of changing the value to null I changed it to 0 instead and that worked beautifully.